# Messenger required for Shaloch Manos?

Tags: halacha, purim, mishloach-manot, shlichus-agency

Does Shalach Manos require a Messenger and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Binyan Tzion, questions if you are Yotzei the Mitzva of Mishloach Manos if you bring it yourself, since Mishloach implies that you must send it with a Shaliach. Others like the Eishel Avrohom and Rav Shlomo Kluger hold that you are certainly Yotzei if you bring it personally. Sending it is a leniency that the Anshei Knesses HaGedola allowed. Moreover you can only make a Shaliach for something that you can do yourself. If you can't give Mishloach Manos by yourself you wouldn't be able to make a Shaliach.

Comment: Great point again

Comment: Your last point is paradoxical. If the Hachamim enacted it to be done specifically through an agent then it would work through an agent. It is a mitzvah dirabanan and the rule of kol detikun rabanan k'ein d'oraisa tiknu is only regarding a mitzvah modeled after an actual d'oraisa concept. On a Yomtov celebrating Torah Shebaal Peh it is appropriate to have a mitzvah that is complete hiddush and not modeled on a di'oraisa.

Comment: Sources? [15 characters]

Answer (score 0):

The [Dvar Avraham chelek 1:13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14443&st=&pgnum=92)  brings a shittah from a reading in the Ran that one needs to use a agent to fulfill mitzvah.

The [Kaf Hachaim 695:41](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9082&st=&pgnum=348) writes the opinion of  Binyan Tzion (Gershon gold sourced) and says that the Torah uses the term send in diffrent cases(Noach,Avraham)but was not done through a agent and he holds one does not need one to fulfill the mitzvah.